# Why "Data Space Used" + "Data Space Available" != "Data Space Total" in docker?

Tags: docker

The `docker info` command output on my system is as follows:

```
# docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 .....
 Data Space Used: 1.821 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 32.92 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.479 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146 GB
......
```

The `Metadata Space Used` + `Metadata Space Available` = `Metadata Space Total`, but why `Data Space Used` + `Data Space Available` != `Data Space Total`?

Comment: Is this for a disk volume? Files are allocated in whole page size blocks: a 1-byte file uses as much disk space as a 10-byte file. When adding up their individual sizes you only 'see' 11 bytes reported but the *disk* free space decreases by 2 entire pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If devicemapper is configured with loop-lvm, it's using a "sparse" storage device. You can specify the size of that device with any size you want, but you can never use more storage than is physically available on your machine.

The size reported as `Data Space Total` is the size that is specified for the "sparse" device (in this case 100 GB). The "Data Space Available" shows the amount of space thats *actually* available on your system.

For example, below, I created a device with 200GB on a system that has 40GB of actual storage space (using the `-s devicemapper --storage-opt dm.loopdatasize=200G` daemon options);

```
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:1-138480-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 305.7 MB
 Data Space Total: 214.7 GB
 Data Space Available: 39.79 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.147 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
```

You can see that it's reporting `Data Space Total: 214.7 GB` (which is 200GB),but show that 39.79 GB is available (the physical space free on the system)

Be aware that when running out of *physical* space, you will get data-corruption, and you may not be able to recover from that, so it's worth monitoring how much space you have left.

For more information about configuring devicemapper (also for *production*, using direct-lvm), see https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/